# Incorrect work jquery plugins bxslider with plugin elevatezoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm begginer in programing. I'm trying to use jquery plugins elevatezoom and bxslider. And I have a little problem.

**What I have**

When I choose one picture from the box, which was created by bxslider plugin, as I understand, the other became invisible, but still exist at the page (in my example at the left top of the page). And when I mouseover this block, the elevate zoomer plugin understand it as a picture for zooming, and start to zoom it. As a result,the page works incorrectly.

**Does anyone know how to solve this problem?**

I also can give the link to the live project

Comment: "_in my example at the left top of the page_", yes please show the example. Also if you could post the HTML structure and the calling function here that you be very helpful.

Comment: http://www.winfieldinteriors.com/bar_led_single_ceiling_pendant_in_aluminium_with_white_inner.html

Here is a live project

Comment: Do you mean calling function from jquery?
And I dont quite understand the question about the HTML stucture
Sorry, but Im beginer in this project (. I just took it today

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to add a class to the active slide object like [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/bxslider-how-to-add-class-to-active-caption-slide) and then create an if statement for active slide objects only.